# Exporting foreign key from many to many relationship to another table sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I've a table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CoursesOfferedToBatches] (
    [CourseId] VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [Batch]    INT          NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Batch] ASC, [CourseId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_OfferedCourses_ToCourses] FOREIGN KEY ([CourseId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Courses] ([Id]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_CoursesOfferedToBatches_ToBatches] FOREIGN KEY ([Batch]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Batches] ([Id])
);
```

When I export CourseId as foreign key from above table into below table as shown below, it gives error shown below after table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[StudentsRegisterToCoursesOffered]
(
    [StudentId] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL , 
    [CourseId] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY ([CourseId], [StudentId]), 
    CONSTRAINT [FK_StudentsRegisterToCoursesOffered_ToStudents] FOREIGN KEY ([StudentId]) REFERENCES [Students]([StudentId]), 
    CONSTRAINT [FK_StudentsRegisterToCoursesOffered_ToCoursesOffered] FOREIGN KEY ([CourseId]) REFERENCES [CoursesOfferedToBatches]([CourseId])
)
```

Error:

> Update cannot proceed due to validation errors.   Please correct the
>   following errors and try again.
>
> SQL71516 :: The referenced table '[dbo].[CoursesOfferedToBatches]'
>   contains no primary or candidate keys that match the referencing
>   column list in the foreign key. If the referenced column is a computed
>   column, it should be persisted.

My question finishes here but for reference I'm adding all relevant tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Courses] (
    [Id]   VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    [Name] VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Students] (
    [StudentId]      UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
    [DepartmentName] VARCHAR (50)     NOT NULL,
    [Address]        VARCHAR (250)    NULL,
    [TwitterLink]    VARCHAR (100)    NULL,
    [FacebookLink]   VARCHAR (100)    NULL,
    [MemberSince]    DATETIME         NULL,
    [ProfileViews]   BIGINT           DEFAULT ((0)) NULL,
    [CNIC]           CHAR (15)        NULL,
    [AboutMe]        VARCHAR (3000)   NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([StudentId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Students_ToStudents] FOREIGN KEY ([StudentId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Users] ([UserId]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Students_ToDepartments] FOREIGN KEY ([DepartmentName]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Departments] ([Name])
);


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Batches] (
    [Id] INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The table `CoursesOfferedToBatches` needs to have its own primary key, which you have created as a compound key `PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Batch] ASC, [CourseId] ASC)`. It is this compound key that would be a foreign key in `StudentsRegisterToCoursesOffered` and not just the `CourseId`.

Comment: When I add following line in the StudentsRegisterToCoursesOffered it gives 2 errors.
CONSTRAINT [FK_StudentsRegisterToCoursesOffered_ToCourseOffered2] FOREIGN KEY ([BatchId]) REFERENCES [CoursesOfferedToBatches]([Batch])

Comment: The foreign key has to refer to the compound primary key you have created in the `CoursesOfferedToBatches ` table. Currently, your primary key refers only to the `BatchId`. I don't even know where `BatchId` is coming from.